# Renting server usage - Solaris (SPARC), AIX and HP-UX (PA-RISC)

Tags: solaris, virtualhost, hp, aix, hp-ux

We do some builds using AIX, Solaris and HP-UX that take about 4 hours per month and we are wondering if there is a service out there that would allow us to do this by renting the usage instead of having to have actual servers in house.

We need AIX, Solaris (Sparc edition) and HPUX (PA-RISC edition as well as Itanium edition)

Does such a service exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that each vendor has labs that you can rent to do exactly that, especially if you're a registered partner or VAR.

Comment: I don't think we are a partner with any Vendors (except dell) but I will inquire though as it may still be better on the budget to rent from them then buying replacement servers (1 each of the ones we need).

I will look into it. Thank you much.